# R Plotly how to add custom names and colors to the legend only

Tags: r, r-plotly, ggplotly

I am using r plotly to plot a stack bar chart and want to replace the legend that is there with a custom legend with names and colors that I choose.  The bottom(gray color) is for the first source to report the intel.  The top part of the bars are colored according to what kind of source(there are three of them).  So light blue would be source1, blue = source2, and darkblue = source3.  I would like to add a custom legend with the four colors:

```
'rgba(128,128,128,1)' = First Reported
'rgba(0,0,139,1)' = source1
'rgba(173,216,230,1)' = source2
'rgba(0,0,255,0.3)' = source 3
```

for the legend and keep the rest of the plot the the way it already is.  This is my code for the plot so far:

```
library(plotly)
x <- c("source1","source2","source3","source4","source5","source6","source7")
y <- c(195760, 161,133199, 22597, 5249, 1276, 115)
y2 <-c(0,137, 36147,0,0,1153, 81)

xform <- list(categoryorder = "array",
              categoryarray = c("source1","source2","source3","source4","source5","source6","source7"))

plot_ly(x=x, y=y2, type='bar',name = 'First Reported',text = y2, textposition = 'inside',textfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
        marker= list(color = c('rgba(128,128,128,1)','rgba(128,128,128,1)', 
                               'rgba(128,128,128,1)','rgba(128,128,128,1)', 
                               'rgba(128,128,128,1)','rgba(128,128,128,1)',
                               'rgba(128,128,128,1)'))) %>%

  add_trace(y=y, name='Not First To Report', text = y,
            marker = list(color = c('rgba(0,0,139,1)','rgba(0,0,139,1)',
                                    'rgba(173,216,230,1)','rgba(0,0,255,0.3)',
                                    'rgba(0,0,255,0.3)','rgba(173,216,230,1)',
                                    'rgba(173,216,230,1'))) %>%
  layout(title = "Counts by Intel Source",xaxis = xform, barmode = 'stack')
```

This is what the graph looks like so far:

[image]